# How to turn off screen with shortcut in Linux?

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, blank-screen

Since my monitor takes an awful lot of time to turn back on after being physically turned off, I'm looking for a command or a simple utility to turn off my screen with a shortcut. Setting a black screensaver is not satisfactory; I want the screen to "hibernate" (the same effect I would get by turning off the computer while leaving the screen physically on).

The same question for Windows: [How can I make my screen blank by a shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/247839/how-can-i-make-my-screen-blank-by-a-shortcut)

Comment: Press STRG a than k and than y

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Try using

```
xset dpms force off
```

to force the screen to turn off.

Comment: That's really great.  For the OP though, when a key is pressed, it turns the screen back on.  I'm not sure if that's desirable.

Comment: Sometimes works better if you do `sleep 1 ; xset dpms force off` otherwise remnants of the last keyboard activity (I guess) sometimes turns the screen back on immediately.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thanks @siva-charan. The only thing I was wondering is how I could ask for a password when I wake the screen. I'm basically using a shortcut to turn off my screen and I would like it to ask for password on wake.

Comment: This does only work if a X server is running/ you have the right to access that X server. Not the ideal solution for a "general case" use/ use in system scripts.

Answer (score 31):

I made a file called `/home/me/bin/blank` and made it executable `chmod +x blank` with the following in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1; xset dpms force off
```

Then I set a shortcut in Gnome3 application "keyboard" (`gnome-control-center keyboard`) to run that script when I push CTRL+ALT+Q.

Man I love linux.

Comment: I liked this :) Just as a little addendum, take a look at https://systembash.com/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-via-command-line-in-ubuntu/ to see how you could set up a timed use of this trick and turn your monitor on/off at specified time

Comment: you mean turning your monitor on at a specified time with cron?

Comment: How do u turn them back on? lol

Comment: @JamieHutber just press a key or move the mouse to turn the screen on again.

Comment: I created a launcher icon on my taskbar that runs the following command: `bash -c "sleep 1; xset dpms force off"`

Comment: This does only work if a X server is running/ you have the right to access that X server. Not the ideal solution for a "general case" use/ use in system scripts.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Alex Cabal script](https://alexcabal.com/turn-your-laptop-screen-off-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-ubuntu-karmic) to turn my two monitors screens off and on and it works very fine for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

# turn screens off/on
# (ɔ) alex cabal

screenOffLockFile=/tmp/screen-off-lock

if [ -f $screenOffLockFile ];
then
    rm $screenOffLockFile
    notify-send "Screen on." -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/devices/display.png
else
    touch $screenOffLockFile
    sleep .5
    while [ -f  $screenOffLockFile ]
    do
        xset dpms force off
        sleep 2
    done
    xset dpms force on
fi
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: @MMM By clicking on the provided link, any interested user can go to a page of the original author of the script that explains in detail how it works.

Comment: Ideally answers are self contained so everything is still here if a linked site disappears.

Comment: This does only work if a X server is running/ you have the right to access that X server. Not the ideal solution for a "general case" use/ use in system scripts.

Answer (score 4):

You can go to your distro's settings, and add a shortcut => putting the command - `xset dpms force off`, then put a hotkey(say F9). That's it, whenever you hit the hotkey, your monitor's screen will turn off

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please don't post irrelevant answers to questions

Comment: Is this irrelevant? If yes, how?

Comment: You describe how to perform this action in Ubuntu. The author requests a solution to this for Linux.

Comment: thank you, I have edited my answer and it should work with most Linux distro's (especially if you use use gnome-shell).

Comment: Perfect, good to know.

Comment: on KDE I had to bind the shortcut to `sleep 1 && xset dpms force off` to prevent it from immediately turning on again

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: This does only work if a X server is running/ you have the right to access that X server. Not the ideal solution for a "general case" use/ use in system scripts.

Answer (score 3):

As a premise, I personally prefer hamstar/Siva Charan solution.
Anyway, I know another possible way could be a script that sets screensaver to blank and then make it start:

```
rem #!/bin/bash

xset s blank ; sleep 1 ; xset s activate
```

So as just not to let unspoken things

Comment: ... And it seems like there's even a more complex one using python for this: https://www.howtogeek.com/61836/how-to-turn-off-your-monitor-with-a-hotkey-in-ubuntu/ (I didn't test it)

Comment: This does only work if a X server is running/ you have the right to access that X server. Not the ideal solution for a "general case" use/ use in system scripts.

Comment: @GolarRamblar : Hey there. OK, despite the OP didn't explicitly mention the will to employ the solution "in system scripts", I saw you put the same comment on (all?) other answers as well, so... If there's one you're aware of, I'd be glad and hope you can suggest something suitable as a solutions for "general case" use here now

Comment: I am also searching for a general solution. This is why I came here. `vbetool dpms off` fails with `Real mode call failed`, and setting my brightness level to 0 still keeps it slightly on (amdgpu). I really need a solution that works from a system deamon (`acpid`) regardless who is logged in and a graphics session is running or not.

Answer (score 2):

[slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock) locks the screen gracefully.

Comment: I just installed it and screen totally locked without turning LED off! and seems there isn't any way to unlock screen again :|

Comment: @MortezaZiaeemehr It's very minimal. Just enter your password and press Enter.