# Chrome remote desktop copy/paste not working

Tags: windows, google-chrome, remote-desktop, windows-registry

Someone on here suggested the below commands to keep the screen off when using chrome remote desktop.
However, running those commands I can no longer copy/paste and the second screen is disabled.

```
reg add HKLM\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome /v RemoteAccessHostRequireCurtain /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f && reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal && Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" /v SecurityLayer /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f && reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" /v UserAuthentication /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f && net stop chromoting && net start chromoting
```

How do I enable copy/paste, and enable the second screen
or how do I reverse those commands
the source of the commands:
[Chrome Remote Desktop: How to turn off the display of the remote computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1034931/chrome-remote-desktop-how-to-turn-off-the-display-of-the-remote-computer)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But for now I have reversed the step by changing values of the following in regedit:

1). HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RemoteAccessHostRequireCurtain to 0

2). HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\UserAuthentication to 0

and the running this command in CMD to make changes to happen:

net stop chromoting && net start chromoting

Let me know if there is any solution to it while Curtain Mode is ON.

Comment: How do you do this man? Is it one time thing, and then you try to generate the token and take control of the machine??? (would the curtain mode be switched on by default?)