# on demand black screen screensaver - black screen without switching off monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, screensaver

I'm using Caffeine to keep Windows from auto-locking due to domain-enforced GPO settings.
When taking a long break, I will manually switch off my external monitor, using the physical power button. However, Windows will switch on my laptop monitor instead (disable multi monitor mode).

Is there a simple way to put a black screensaver, on demand? Windows default screensaver settings obviously doesn't work in this case, because I'm using Caffeine and it will never get activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file containing the [Screen Saver command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/screen-saver-command-line). The command should look like `%systemroot%\system32\scrnsave.scr /s`. This command starts the screen saver program which defaults to a black screen.

If you want something more complex I would advise you to take a look at [NirCmd](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). This utility gives you the ability to do random miscellaneous stuff in Windows from the command line and therefore also from scripts. The [monitor](https://nircmd.nirsoft.net/monitor.html) command might be of interest to you but I am not sure how it will behave on your laptop.

Comment: awesome this works perfectly. Works as a great workaround to another issue, preserve opened window positions on multiple monitors. Switching off a monitor, even temporarily, will move all the windows to another screen.

Comment: i tried multimonitor from nirsoft, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html, it can't turn off my laptop screen, works for the external monitor though.

Answer (score 0):

[Multiscreen Blank](http://dl.nookkin.com/products/multiscreenblank/)

This neat app solves the problem perfectly. I can simply right click and blacken all monitors on demand.

[image]

[image]

Apparently, you can use it to block out certain parts of the screen if you're the kind that is easily distracted by blinking lights. Or just to avoid information overload. Check out the "New Scrap" function.

Comment: Did you happen to create this app? This site is not against anyone promoting work they have done, as long as it is in the context of an answer, but one should generally be transparent about your work if you created this tool.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 no i did not create this. Just something I found that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

Found a couple of excellent solutions here, [How can I make my screen blank by a shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/247839/how-can-i-make-my-screen-blank-by-a-shortcut) I'm using the suggestion by user Polynomial.

Simply run this command to activate the default screensaver (set to blank screen prior),

```
cmd /c scrnsave.scr /s
```

In autohotkey, mapped to a shortcut,

```
Capslock & f4:: Run cmd /c scrnsave.scr /s
```

I tried the other methods, but they will all lock the screen. I don't want that to happen.

```
1) SendMessage 0x112, 0xF170, 2,,Program Manager
2) nircmd.exe monitor off
3) nircmd.exe screensaver
```